# Why can I get Windows 10 legally, officially and free?

Tags: windows-10, iso-image

If I go to [this microsoft.com link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/software-download/windows10ISO), I can easily get a free, legal, and completely official ISO of Windows 10. If memory serves, this is where I got the ISO that I used in one of my virtual machines and it worked perfectly with no catches or unexpected behavior.

My question is this: It is well known that [buying Windows 10 is not cheap](https://www.google.com/search?q=windows%2010&tbm=shop), so **why** do Microsoft allow people to easily get it for free? Is there some unexpected catch? Is this somehow inferior to the versions of Windows 10 that I'd get in a shop (the link is presumably for Home edition?)? Is it intended for some audience that I'm unaware of? What do Microsoft gain from this (data?)?

Comment: Your question is answered in the EULA (end user license agreement) included in the software you downloaded. It clearly states that you must have a license to use the software. Obtaining the bits is not the same thing as having a license.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If I go to this microsoft.com link, I can easily get a free, legal, and completely official ISO of Windows 10. If memory serves, this is where I got the ISO that I used in one of my virtual machines and it worked perfectly with no catches or unexpected behavior.

A license has not been required to download a Windows ISO for the better part of a decade.  Microsoft does not require a license key to download Windows 8, Windows 8.1, and Windows 10 ISOs.  Like all versions of Windows, during the installation process, a license key will be requested.  If one is not provided the installation will be unactivated, and Windows will continue to prompt the user, for a legitimate license key to whatever version of Windows that was installed.

There is no legitimate way to run any version of Windows without a license key. While there are ways to run evaluation installations of Windows, that’s only possible in a virtual machine which can only be armed a limited amount of times, likewise running Windows unactivated isn’t legitimate.  There might be more examples of an evaluation of Windows installations, but the virtual machine that Microsoft distributes for free is the best example.

> Is this somehow inferior to the versions of Windows 10 that I'd get in a shop?

It actually is the exact same image.  The installation media that is created by the Media Creation Tool contains both Windows 10 Home and Windows 10 Professional.  It also contains both 32-bit and 64-bit versions of those editions.  Any other edition of Windows will have its own ISO due to legal and regional restrictions.

> Is it intended for some audience that I'm unaware of?

It is intended for a Windows user.

> What does Microsoft gain from this?

They don't gain anything from it.  The image they distribute is the exact same image that would be contained in an installation media that they distribute.  Microsoft creates both installation images, so it makes sense, they would be identical.

> Why does Microsoft allow people to easily get it for free?

It simply isn't worth the trouble, to prevent people from downloading an ISO to an operating system, that they cannot use without a license key.

> Is there some unexpected catch?

The ISO you download from Microsoft is identical to the ISO you would receive if you purchased the installation media from Microsoft.  In reality, the installation media from Microsoft is actually older then the ISO you can download today.  This is obviously due to the fact, it takes time to produce and distribute the installation media, this is also a factor in allowing people to easily create their own installation media.

> it's not legal, however, they've neglected to include any way of catching you" seems hard to believe.

You could say this about any software that requires a license in order to activate it.  The bottom line is that every single Windows installation requires a license in order to use it.  **The fact some people choose to ignore this requirement does not mean that requirement does not exist.**

Comment: Your last sentence would be a perfect TL;DR. It seems to be what folks get the most confused about.

Comment: It does make it a lot easier to do with reinstalls - the initial "upgrades" have digital entitlements that automatically pick up the licences on a reinstall. It also acts as a way to get a trial version if you need to do a quick bit of testing.  It is also the only way to do an update on systems with limited storage. They have it available because, well, its *useful*

Comment: Digital Entitlements is a license to Windows 10. I am not entirely sure what "it" is and how "it" makes it easier to do reinstalls.